# What version of Go is supported on OSX 10.7.5 (Lion)

Tags: go

I have an older MacBook that can't be upgraded past OSX 10.7.5.  What is the latest binary release of the Go tools can I install on it?  According to the [golang downloads page](https://golang.org/dl/), the current "featured" download (1.6.2) requires OSX 10.8, but for most prior releases, the page doesn't state the OS version compatibility requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Go 1.4.2 was the last official release that officially mentioned support for versions of OSX before 10.8. For that release there were two binary packages: one with an `osx10.8` suffix, and one with an `osx10.6` suffix.

Already in Go 1.5, only OSX 10.8 was mentioned as being supported. See: https://web.archive.org/web/20150820055435/https://golang.org/dl/

Of course, you can download any version and build it from source, and that's what I'd do if I were stuck with an old version of OSX.

Comment: I don't have an OSX to confirm, however there's a big chance that Go dropped support for certain instructions on that old hardware, so you *may* end up with broken binaries even if it compiles.